# I already have few php files running in my apache2 in ubuntu but when I create new php file, the browser does not shows the UI or it does not run

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp, apache2

This happened in XAMPP also, so I uninstalled it and installed apache, php, mysql and phpmyadmin all separately.

There is not issue with the code. To proceed with my work, I also, tried to use the code in the existing file and try to run but it does not work.

What is the issue? Is there any file count restriction on these web server or what?

Why I am unable to see the web page?

Comment: Hello. With the informations given, we can't really help you. Can you be more precise? Tell us what you've tried, tell us step by step how and where you created the file, what you put in and how you tried to access it.

Comment: Most likely a permissions issue - your logs should contain a description of what went wrong.

Comment: I have my files in /var/www/html/ and it runs well. But when I created a new php file and run it on a browser, those new files alone do not run. When i try to view source on the bowser, its null!

Comment: @symcbean, can you tell me how to check it? I am newbie!

Comment: The log says - [24/Jul/2017:16:40:55 +0000] "GET /ot/login.php HTTP/1.1" 500 185 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"

Comment: @symcbean, Thanks a lot. Yes there is a fatal error in my code. I have turned off php error as I have configured it to be in production. Thanks a lot all for your precision time.

Answer (score 0):

i think folder permission issue.
use this command

```
$sudo chmod -R  777 /your_file_contain_folder
```

Comment: Which MVC you are using .